# Does Google Docs Have any Externally Accessible Link to Show a Doc and Its Associated Sharing Dialog?

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I am working on GNOME's Documents application for my Google Summer of Code project. The Google documents listing that we get from libgdata is organized in a Feed object which is composed by Entry objects (an entry map to a document). Each Entry has an "alternate" link that maps to a browser accessible version. We are currently allowing users to open their Google docs in the browser via such an "alternate" link.Each Entry also has an associated "access rule" Feed which is in turn composed by Entries specifying permissions, but neither of those seem to have an alternate link.I am wondering if there is any way to access an alternate link to show a Google document and the associated Google docs sharing dialog in a webkit webview? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Documents List API documentation for details on how to manage sharing:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#managing_sharing_permissions_of_resources_via_access_control_lists_acls

Also, consider using the newer Drive API which exposes the same functionality:

https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-sharing